# 'No such directory' when activating a Pipenv on Windows

Tags: python, pipenv, python-venv

I've created a pipenv environment and now I'm creating a shell script called bootstrap.sh to activate it and run a flask server, but the following line is producing an error

bootstrap.sh reads as follows

```
 #!/bin/sh

...

source "$(pipenv --venv)\\Scripts\\activate"

...
```

Running simply `pipenv --venv` returns `C:\Users\johng\.virtualenvs\cashman-flask-project-2vwc8e6G`

But executing the shell script returns a No such file or directory error

```
$ source bootstrap.sh
/Scripts/activate: No such file or directoryask-project-2vwc8e6G
```

This is in the vsCode bash terminal on Windows 10. The file certainly exists and can be navigated to, so what is causing this?